# clickhouse-mysql get error: ImportError: cannot import name 'charset_to_encoding' from 'pymysql.charset'

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, clickhouse

```sh
[root@mytestuse pymysql]# clickhouse-mysql
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/clickhouse-mysql", line 5, in <module>
    from clickhouse_mysql import main
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/clickhouse_mysql/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .main import Main
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/clickhouse_mysql/main.py", line 21, in <module>
    from clickhouse_mysql.config import Config
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/clickhouse_mysql/config.py", line 4, in <module>
    from clickhouse_mysql.reader.mysqlreader import MySQLReader
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/clickhouse_mysql/reader/mysqlreader.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pymysqlreplication import BinLogStreamReader
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysqlreplication/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .binlogstream import BinLogStreamReader
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysqlreplication/binlogstream.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .packet import BinLogPacketWrapper
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysqlreplication/packet.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pymysqlreplication import constants, event, row_event
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysqlreplication/row_event.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pymysql.charset import charset_to_encoding
ImportError: cannot import name 'charset_to_encoding' from 'pymysql.charset' (/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/charset.py)
[root@mytestuse pymysql]#
```

system info:
CentOS Linux release 7.6
python info:
python 3.7.8

Comment: I think need to add the issue to https://github.com/altinity/clickhouse-mysql-data-reader/issues

Comment: thanks for you advice.I haved add issue to it.

Comment: see answer here [ImportError: cannot import name 'charset_to_encoding' #183](https://github.com/Altinity/clickhouse-mysql-data-reader/issues/183)

Comment: I fix the error,add：
vim /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/charset.py
#TODO: remove this
def charset_to_encoding(name):
    """Convert MySQL's charset name to Python's codec name"""
    if name in ('utf8mb4', 'utf8mb3'):
        return 'utf8'
    return name